# dyld: __dyld section not supported Xcode 10 error

Tags: ios, xcode

I've updated Xcode to version 10. After running, application crashing with message log "dyld: __dyld section not supported in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AAAAAA-AAAA-AAA-9337-95F8907E0B50/MyApp.app/MyApp"[image: image error]

Comment: Did you clean your build folder and rebuild after upgrading?

Comment: alt + cmd + shift + K for clean build folder and run again

Comment: @EneaDume cmd, not cntrl.

Comment: you're right, fixed it

Comment: cleaning build folder (derived data) not helping, check it before.

Comment: update: problem only on iOS 12, on iOS 11 everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the crash is that the __DATA __dyld section is missing from the binary. I don't know yet why the section is not created anymore. With Xcode 9 binaries are generated that contain the section, with Xcode 10 its not longer generated.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, in my case problem was outdated pod. Hope it helps.